# Hadoop on windows with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, cygwin

I read a post here on stack overflow about this link being very good for  hadoop deployment on windows - http://v-lad.org/Tutorials/Hadoop/12%20-%20format%20the%20namendoe.html

Problem is when I format the namenode as given on that page, after 
    bin/hadoop namenode -format

I get the following error: 
Maybe its a problem with my environmental variables but I'm not sure.

```
bin/hadoop: line 330: C:\Program: command not found
bin/hadoop: line 395: C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0\bin/bin/java: No such   
file/directory
bin/hadoop: line 395: exec: C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0\bin/bin/java: cannot 
execute: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You JAVA_HOME is wrongly configured and don't use jdk7, instead use jdk6.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I did ln -s path_to_jdk7 name_of_link; export JAVA_HOME=name_of_link.

Comment: Burt now, I have a new error -IllegalArgumentException when trying to run tasktracker. Saying that cannot start tasktracker because there is no valid host::port authority. My core-site.xml is good. But still the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Just set you JAVA_HOME properly, it resolved my issue-

anwar@dell-pc ~/hadoop-0.20.203.0

$ export JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_02"